# C segmentation fault while using structures

Tags: c, data-structures, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to write a data structure with two elements, and then defining a variable of that type struct. However, after initializing the variable in the main function, I'm getting segmentation fault and I don't know why.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> 

struct AnimalSizes {
    char stringName[50]; 
    double sizeLength; 
    } animalSizes[2]; 

int main()
{

    struct AnimalSizes *snakes; 
    strcpy(snakes[0].stringName,"Anaconda"); 
    snakes[0].sizeLength=3.7; 
    strcpy(snakes[1].stringName,"Python"); 
    snakes[1].sizeLength= 2.4; 
    printf("%c", *snakes[0].stringName); 
    printf("%lf", snakes[0].sizeLength); 
    printf("%c", *snakes[1].stringName); 
    printf("%lf", snakes[1].sizeLength);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You try to `strcpy` to destination where is no allocated memory. That is undefined behavior.
You should first allocate enough memory to hold two `AnimalSizes` instances:

```
struct AnimalSizes *snakes;
snakes = malloc(2 * sizeof(struct AnimalSizes));
```

Also, here
`printf("%c", snakes[0].stringName);`
you are trying to output the first character of `stringName`. I assume, what you rather want to do is to output whole string with `%s`.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your answer!  I was wondering why we had to use dynamic memory allocation. I'm kind of lost in that topic and any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You've declared a pointer to a `struct AnimalSizes`, and you have declared an array `struct AnimalSizes[2]`, but you have not made the pointer point to this array:

```
int main()
{

    struct AnimalSizes *snakes = &animalSizes[0]; 
...
}
```

Alternatively, you may choose to not declare a global variable, rather choosing to allocate memory in `main`:

```
#include <stdlib.c>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> 

struct AnimalSizes {
    char stringName[50]; 
    double sizeLength; 
    }; 

int main()
{

    struct AnimalSizes *snakes = (struct AnimalSizes*) malloc(2*sizeof(struct AnimalSizes)); 
    strcpy(snakes[0].stringName,"Anaconda"); 
    snakes[0].sizeLength=3.7; 
    strcpy(snakes[1].stringName,"Python"); 
    snakes[1].sizeLength= 2.4; 
    printf("%c", *snakes[0].stringName); 
    printf("%lf", snakes[0].sizeLength); 
    printf("%c", *snakes[1].stringName); 
    printf("%lf", snakes[1].sizeLength);
    free(snakes);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the following proposed code:

1. eliminates any need for `malloc()` and `free()`
2. performs the desired functionality
3. separates the definition of the struct from any instance of the struct.
4. inserts some spacing between the first letter of the snake name and the 'size' of the snake, for readability
5. applies certain other changes to the code for 'human' readability

and now the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> 

struct AnimalSizes 
{
    char stringName[50]; 
    double sizeLength; 
};


int main( void )
{
    struct AnimalSizes snakes[2]; 

    strcpy(snakes[0].stringName,"Anaconda"); 
    snakes[0].sizeLength=3.7; 

    strcpy(snakes[1].stringName,"Python"); 
    snakes[1].sizeLength= 2.4; 

    printf("%c  ",  snakes[0].stringName[0]); 
    printf("%lf\n", snakes[0].sizeLength); 

    printf("%c  ",  snakes[1].stringName[0]); 
    printf("%lf\n", snakes[1].sizeLength);
    return 0;
}
```

a run of the proposed code outputs:

```
A  3.700000
P  2.400000
```